# Regex to match a digit between parentheses

Tags: regex

I want to match a regex for a digit(s) between parentheses. For example in these 3 example strings i need to math the (4) in every string

> Toy Story Card Game Something Wild! Case (4) English Version

> Toy Story Card Game Something Wild! Case (4)

> Toy Story Card Game (hoi) Something Wild! Case (4)

But the (hoi) shouldn't match.

What i have tried:

`\(([^\)]+)\)$` --> only matches the last example

`[\d\()-]+` --> only matches first example.

Answer (score 0):

The first try was close, you just anchored it at the end (and perhaps you thought you were escaping `)` in your character class, but that's not how character classes work):

```
\((\d+)\)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it could be done in Java

```
String [] sentences = {
   "Toy Story Card Game Something Wild! Case (4) English Version (9)",
   "Toy Story Card Game Something Wild! Case (4)",
   "Toy Story Card Game (hoi) Something Wild! Case (4)"
};
```

- The regex is a capture group that escapes the outer parens since they have special meaning in regex contexts. The lashes need to be escaped since they have special meanings in strings.
- find() will find all matches until it returns false.

```
String regex = "\\((\\d+)\\)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
for (String sentence : sentences) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(sentence);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

prints

```
4
9
4
4
```